# What does this WCF exception mean?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

The exception message is

> The client's security session did not receive a 'close response' message from the service within the configured timeout

Any valuable information?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Increase, Max concurrent calls in WCF.
It can be worked for you.